# moving a database from sqlServer to phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql-server, data-transfer

i have a WordPress site and had created a database in my host within phpMyAdmin.
since SQL server is much more easier to use ratter than phpMyAdmin, I switched to SQL server and made another database with tables and records in it.
now i want to transfer my DB from SQL server to phpMyAdmin, beside my old database that i created before.
I tried export and import but i got a lot of errors!
I would be thankful if anyone can help

Comment: Just an idea. But maybe you'll have better luck with using the migration wizard in MySql workbench?  An artikel about that [here](https://mysqlworkbench.org/2012/07/migrating-from-ms-sql-server-to-mysql-using-workbench-migration-wizard/).

Comment: _...host within phpMyAdmin..._ Phypmyadmin is just a MySQL administration tool

Comment: " I tried export and import but i got a lot of errors!" SQL server uses different SQL.. Where MySQL uses `AUTO_INCREMENT`.. SQL server uses `IDENTITY(1,1)` for example..

Comment: There are significant differences between sql server and mysql - it's almost never a good idea to develop in one and put into production in another.